# Find data between two values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, return-value

I have a range of articles;

```
Product Width   height
6995851 2200    1500
6907240 2500    1500
6992008 2700    1500
6961925 2700    1500
6924509 3000    1500
6982492 3000    2000
```

And I have a number of models;

```
Product Width   height  Extra room  Fits
9PARX   2470    1530    50          
WGTQB   2970    1530    50          
R3FEA   2970    1530    50          
O03TU   2970    1530    50          
7BUIT   3170    1530    50          
H7XSB   3170    1530    50          
NF75G   2970    1770    50          
6X9EG   3470    1770    50          
9Q9WJ   3470    1770    50          
19UQR   4000    2100    50          
FCQDM   3470    1770    50
```

I want the "Fits" in my number of models to tell me, with the added extra room, what article that is greater than that that will fit. Ie, Product "9PARX" would be a total of 2470+50=2820 wide and 1530+50=1580 tall, that means in tallness they all but "6982492" is valid, and in wideness "6992008" and "6961925" would be the ones that fit. Thus, in fits for "9PARX" the result will be "6992008" and, most desired in a second column, "6961925". Is it possible to make this with a formula? That way I can easily import [x] amount of models and update articles as time passes by and really easy know what fits best where.

Comment: Do you want to fit items from first table into the second one or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this can be done using Array formula, but it will be really slow.

Given that your second table (table with Extra Rooms) column Product starts in Column **G**  and we start from row 2, then you can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A:C;MATCH(1;(B:B=MAX(IF(B:B<(H2+J2);B:B;"")))*(C:C=MAX(IF(C:C<(I2+J2);C:C;"")));0);1)
```

Some explanations:

```
MAX(IF(B:B<(H2+J2);B:B;""))
```

The formula above Sums Width + Extra and then tries to find the Maximum number which is less than the result (so that your product still fits in the room)

Our Match formula:

```
MATCH(1;(B:B=MAX(IF(B:B<(H2+J2);B:B;"")))*(C:C=MAX(IF(C:C<(I2+J2);C:C;"")));0)
```

This is multiple criteria Match function. We are looking for number 1 which is TRUE result for our Match criteria. Basically, we can have as many criterias here as we want where what we do is that we multiply results (either **1** for TRUE or **0** for FALSE) and if all conditions are TRUE then we have found our match).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, amazing piece of code! Unfortunately, it's not working for me! :( Using Swedish Excel 2010, believe work where this will be implemented uses Excel 2014 (don't quote me on that just yet). I first got name error that I fixed by http://en.excel-translator.de/. Howeer now it says "värdefel", ie error in the values or something similar. How can I help you help me on this, what do you require me to do given you are still up for the task.

Comment: well, you can send me the excel file (keep only few lines of data in case they are sensitive) and I will send it back

Comment: also have you entered the formula as an array? (Ctrl + Shift + Enter)

Comment: I tried CTRL+Shift+Enter and it caused nothing to happen. However I found a bunch of resources on it on the web and it seems quite awesome! Will look into that later, so thanks for that!

Onto this issue, I have posted the spreadsheet with just one cell as your formula, hope that is what you sought. It's on my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sapseixwymx7ziu/Bok1.xlsx

Comment: I entered the formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter and it worked without a problem. Nonetheless the formula is not 100% correct but it should point you to the right direction. Please make sure you close thread if you have found your answer.

Comment: I even got it to work now what I had to do is get inside that index value to the point where you get that neat little window with all it's formulas and such, then select row where all match formula is and do that shortcut. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind though that Array formulas can **Really** slow down calculation speed